# SAPUI5 unable to get table editable cell value

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to get the cell value of an editable column on a button click but i am getting all selected row values except the editable column value.

Please let me know how can i get the value.

Below is my code:

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    sId: "Master Table",
    selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Multi,
    selectionBehavior: sap.ui.table.SelectionBehavior.Row,
    enableCellFilter : true
  });

// define the Table columns and the binding values
  oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "ID"}),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"{ID}",editable : false,filterProperty: "ID"})
  }));

oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Name"}),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"{NAME}",editable : false})
  }));

oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Address"}),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"{ADDRESS}",editable : false})
  }));

oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "PIN CODE"}),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text:"{PIN_CODE}",editable : false})
  }));

oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Mobile Number"}),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({text:"",editable : true})
  }));
```

**Here mobile number is my editable field which the end user can fill in the table.**

I have a button and on the click of the button i am trying to fetch the selected row values as below:

```
oButtonUpdate.attachPress(function(){
    if(oTable.getSelectedIndices().length==0){
        sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("No Row Selected");
        return;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < oTable.getSelectedIndices().length; i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            alert(oTable.getRows()[oTable.getSelectedIndices()[i]].getCells()[j].getText());
        }
    }

});
```

Now the above code only returns me till PIN Code.

How can i get the value of the editable cell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with the cell being editable.

While "TextView" has "getText()" to retrieve the value, "TextField" has "getValue()".

See the documentation link [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.commons.TextField/methods/getValue).

Either you change the TextField to a TextView (if possible), or you adjust your loop to the following snippet:

```
for(j=0;j<4;j++){
    var oControl = oTable.getRows()[oTable.getSelectedIndices()[i]].getCells()[j];
    if (oControl.getText) {
        alert(oControl.getText());
    }
    else if (oControl.getValue) {
        alert(oControl.getValue());
    }
}
```

The "else if" part is optional since just "else" would suffice in this case.